# SQL - How do I sum/aggregate certain rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `t` that looks like this (which is itself the result of a long SQL query):

```
    ID     | Name     | Active     | Sales
----------------------------------------------
    1        Amy        t            50
    2        Bill       f            4
    3        Chip       t            127
    4        Dana       t            543
    5        Eve        f            20
```

I'm looking to combine the inactive users (`"Active" = f`) so that I end up with a resultant table like this:

```
    ID     | Name     | Active     | Sales
----------------------------------------------
    1        Amy        t            50
    3        Chip       t            127
    4        Dana       t            543
    0        -          f            24
```

Is there a way to do this without repeating the initial query to get that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
select id, name, active, sales
from t
where active
union all
select 0, NULL, f, sum(sales)
from t
where not active;
```

If this is the result of a complex view, you might not want to reference it twice.  If so, you can use aggregation:

```
select (case when active then id end) as id,
       (case when active then name end) as name,
       active,
       sum(sales) as sales
from t
group by (case when active then id end),
         (case when active then name end) as name,
         active;
```

Comment: you're right, I don't want to reference it twice.  I will try out your second code block.

Comment: for the second query, the second case when is wrong

Comment: "case when active then name" would be good, use the answer from @avb and mix it with this one to get the correct query.

Answer (score 3):

used another table with boolean for sampling (used kvazi int, boolean and kvazi text attributes) ((different from above by having not union and just one case))(((used `sum` as I thought that's what you want - aggregate over a case))):

```
t=# select
  case when not rolsuper then '-' else rolname::text end
, rolsuper
, sum(oid::text::int)
from pg_roles
group by case when not rolsuper then '-' else rolname::text end,rolsuper;
 rolname  | rolsuper |  sum
----------+----------+--------
 -        | f        | 144394
 vao      | t        |  16555
 postgres | t        |     10
(3 rows)
```

so for you should be smth like:

```
select
      case when not active then 0 else id end
    , case when not active then '-' else name end
    , active
    , sum(sales)
    from t
    group by 
      case when not active then 0 else id end
    , case when not active then '-' else name end
    , active;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
    ,Name
    ,Active
    ,Sales
FROM my TABLE
WHERE Active = 't'

UNION

SELECT 0
    ,''
    ,Active
    ,COUNT(Sales)
FROM my TABLE
WHERE Active = 'f'
GROUP BY Active
```

Answer (score 0):

and here's without unions:

```
select IIF(Active = 'f', 0, ID) ID, IIF(Active = 'f', '-', Name) Name, Active, SUM(Sales) Sales
from t
group by IIF(Active = 'f', 0, ID), IIF(Active = 'f', '-', Name), Active
```

Comment: Good query but IIF is for access not postgresql